# Can't use toString() method of object inside ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I'm trying to use `toString()` method of an object inside `ArrayList`, and it was printing the memory address instead the expected values. I translated my classes to English, sorry if I forget something, just quest if you don't understand. **Let's see my code:**

#### Schedule class (I supressed getters and setters):

```
static Professor professor;
static Room room;
static Classroom classroom;

public String toString() {
        return "Schedule [getProfessor()=" + getProfessor() + ", getRoom()="
                + getRoom() + ", getClassRoom()=" + getClassRoom() + ", getClass()=" + getClass() + ", hashCode()="
                + hashCode() + ", toString()=" + super.toString() + "]";
}
```

#### School

```
ArrayList<Professor> professor = new ArrayList<Professor>();
ArrayList<Room> room = new ArrayList<Room>();
ArrayList<Classroom> classroom = new ArrayList<Classroom>(); 
public ArrayList<Schedule[][]> sched = new ArrayList<Schedule[][]>();
```

I'm using genetic algorithm (at moment I'm learning about it, so, I don't know a lot), here is my "population generator":

#### Population

```
public static void generatePopulation(School school){

        // Shuffle the arraylist for generate a random population
        Collections.shuffle(school.getProfessor());
        Collections.shuffle(school.getClassroom());
        Collections.shuffle(school.getRoom());

        Schedule[][] sched1 = new Schedule[1][1];

        // Generate population (just a little test to see if it works)
        sched1[0][0].addEverything(school.getProfessor().get(0), school.getClassroom().get(0), school.getRoom().get(0));
        school.sched.add(sched);
```

#### Main

```
 (... school and associations created ...)
    Population.generatePopulation(school);
    System.out.println(school.getSched().isEmpty()); // it returns false, that is, isn't empty
    System.out.println(school.getSched().get(0).toString()); 
    // returns "[[Lentidades.Schedule;@40914272" (entidades = name of my package)
```

So, why I'm receiving memory position instead the expected values?
I think I don't forgot nothing, but if you see something strange in this code, just send a question and I will explain / paste the remaining code.

Comment: It's not really the memory address per SE. It is your object that has been serialized to a string

Comment: Why are your variables static? That's almost certainly a bad idea.

Comment: Yep, now I see that in my project hahaha. Already fixed that (:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are receiving an `array` of `Schedule`s, therefore your `toString()` method is never used.

Look at the `[[` part of the `[[Lentidades.Schedule;@40914272` output, this tells you that an 2-dimensional `array` is being printed.

As @JonSkeet and @MarounMaroun points out, an easy way to print `arrays` is by using [`Arrays.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) for one-dimensional `arrays`, or [`Arrays.deepToString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) for multi-dimensional.

Comment: To add to this, you can use Arrays.toString to print an array's contents: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(java.lang.Object[])

Comment: Thanks @Keppil ! But I'm still getting errors. I wrote: System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(school.getSched().get(0))); and I'm receiving "[[null]]".

Comment: @FernandoPaladini: That means that something went wrong populating your array, you only have one `null` schedule. My guess is that you should look at the `addEverything()` method for clues.

Comment: I delete "static" type from my attributes and methods of Schedule class, now I'm getting the following error: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException"

In this code: sched1[0][0].addEverything(school.getProfessor().get(0), school.getClassroom().get(0), school.getRoom().get(0));

Comment: @FernandoPaladini: There are a lot of references in that line that can be null. Go through them one by one and make sure they are all initialized properly.

Comment: @Keppil Ok. I changed my "addEverythingcode to: "sched1[0][0].setProfessor(school.getProfessor().get(0));" and I still getting trouble. I will search my code and try to find the problems. In a few minutes I put the result, thanks :P

Comment: I can't find the error. I will try find with my teacher the answer. Thanks Keppil, the best answer is yours.